# Sorting multiple sheets - code clean up

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for some guidance on sorting columns across multiple sheets.

I have 2 data sets (tab1: ABC and tab2: XYZ).
I'm trying to sort both sheets (range column A to column J) by column A in descending order.

This is what I have so far... it is recorded.  I would very much like to clean up my code and also look for better ways to approach sorting by columns.  Any help/tips would be appreciated.

```
Sub sortingcolumns()

Application.Goto Reference:="ABC!A1"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ABC").sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ABC").sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ABC").sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:K187")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With



Application.Goto Reference:="XYZ!RC"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("XYZ").sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("XYZ").sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("XYZ").sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:J179")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: did my answer, or anyone else's, address your question correctly?

Comment: hi whytheeq, not yet unfortunately.  i tried tpkaplan's method but i did not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using "with" you can combine those into one bigger with statement:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ABC").sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
    .SetRange Range("A2:K187")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Also, you can remove the .header, .matchcase, .orientation, .sortmethod if you don't need to sort by those.

Answer (score 0):

I like to fully qualify all objects e.g. `ActiveWorkbook` becomes `Excel.ActiveWorkbook`. This is a personal choice.

Also I like to avoid `Active...` objects so if this code only needs to act on the workbook where the code is stored then switch to `ThisWorkbook`

```
With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ABC").sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add _
       Key:=Range("A1"), _
       SortOn:=Excel.xlSortOnValues, _
       Order:=Excel.xlDescending, _
       DataOption:= Excel.xlSortTextAsNumbers
    .SetRange Range("A2:K187")
    .Header = Excel.xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = Excel.xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = Excel.xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

If it needs to act on a separate workbook then use an object variable. For example if the target columns are in a book called `foo.xlsx` (that we assume is open)

```
Dim myFooBk As Excel.workbook
Set myFooBk  = Excel.workbooks("foo.xlsx")

With myFooBk.Worksheets("ABC").sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add _
       Key:=Range("A1"), _
       SortOn:=Excel.xlSortOnValues, _
       Order:=Excel.xlDescending, _
       DataOption:= Excel.xlSortTextAsNumbers
    .SetRange Range("A2:K187")
    .Header = Excel.xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = Excel.xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = Excel.xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Also the `with` could be altered slightly by moving the `.Sort` inside the clause:

```
Dim myFooBk As Excel.workbook
Set myFooBk  = Excel.workbooks("foo.xlsx")

With myFooBk.Worksheets("ABC")
    .sort.SortFields.Clear
    .sort.SortFields.Add _
       Key:= .Range("A1"), _  '<<more specific now as `.` infront of Range
       SortOn:=Excel.xlSortOnValues, _
       Order:=Excel.xlDescending, _
       DataOption:= Excel.xlSortTextAsNumbers
    .sort.SetRange .Range("A2:K187") '<<more specific now as `.` infront of Range
    .sort.Header = Excel.xlNo
    .sort.MatchCase = False
    .sort.Orientation = Excel.xlTopToBottom
    .sort.SortMethod = Excel.xlPinYin
    .sort.Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
call sortingcolumns ActiveWorkbook.worksheets("ABC"), 2, 187
call sortingcolumns ActiveWorkbook.worksheets("XYZ"), 2, 179

Sub sortingcolumns(sht as Worksheet, First as Integer, Last as Integer)

With sht.sort
  .sortfields.clear
  .sortfields.add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
      DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
  .setrange = sht.range("A" & First & ":K" & Last)
  .Header = xlNo
  .MatchCase = False
  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
  .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

You could modify it to provide the first and last columns, as well, then you have a nice utility function that can sort any range for you just by passing the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can shorten it substantially:

```
Sub sortingcolumns()
    Worksheets("ABC").Range("A2:K187").sort key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlDescending
    Worksheets("XYZ").Range("A2:J179").sort key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlDescending
End sub
```

I made the following changes:

1. I used the (old) `range.sort` construct instead of the (newer) `worksheet.sort`.  With the old construct, you simply identify the range to sort and then apply the .sort method with the appropriate arguments.  The newer one is also more flexible but also more complicated to use.
2. The only arguments you need are `key1` and `Order1`.  If you wanted to sort ascending, you could also eliminate the `order1` argument; then you'd have just one argument.

If you don't specify an argument, Excel will use the default.  All of the arguments in your snippet are the default arguments for the sort method.  Therefore you don't need to specify them.

Comment: This didn't work.  Run-time error '1004': The sort reference is not valid.  Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.